# Is it possible to use an array of bits instead of an array of bytes?

Tags: rust, bit

Is it possible to use an array of bits instead of an array of bytes in Rust like the C++ version below?

```cpp
std::bitset<8> b2(42);          // [0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
```

I am sending packets over the network that have either a true or false value, so there is no need to use, for example, 34 bytes (could be even higher, up to 64000 bytes) when I can just use `((34 % 8) != 0 + 34 / 8 = 5)` bytes.

I could just make a function (or crate) doing this job, but isn't it something that should already be part of the Rust library?

Comment: TL;DR the duplicate: nothing like this in the language or standard library.

Comment: Rust _likes_ using crates; it's a good idea to become comfortable with that notion if you wish to use Rust long-term.